# paypal amount changing when value is 4 figures

Tags: php, variables, paypal

This is so strange. I am sending the value e.g. 4240 ($4,240)

The variable $amount is exactly "4240", but when it goes through the api and I echo it, it suddenly becomes  4%2C240.00.

The API is

```
        $nvpStr = "&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType";
    $nvpStr .= "&AMT=$amount";
    $nvpStr .= "&ACCT=$creditCardNumber&EXPDATE=$padDateMonth$expDateYear&CVV2=$cvv2Number";
    $nvpStr .= "&FIRSTNAME=$firstName&LASTNAME=$lastName&EMAIL=$email";
    $nvpStr .= "&STREET=$address1&CITY=$city&STATE=$state&COUNTRYCODE=$country&ZIP=$zip";
    $nvpStr .= "&INVNUM=$invoice&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID&";
```

When I echo $nvpStr, it becomes

```
&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&AMT=4%2C240.00&ACCT=
```

I have tested the variable amount, and when echoed it is 4240. So how can it change to 4%2C240.00

If the value is under 1000, and just 3 figures, there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear on the question, but that all looks expected to me.  %2C is just the URL encoded value for a comma.  So `urlencode("4,240.00") == "4%2C240.00"`.

Comment: But I don't have a comma, its just 4240. Why is it inserting the comma?

Answer (score 0):

The url is encoded. This will decode it:

```
$nvpStr .= "&AMT=" . urldecode($amount);
```

The decoded string is "4,240.00" because that's how paypal formats it.
If you need to remove the comma you can use `str_replace(',', '', urldecode($amount));`
Or `str_replace('%2C', '', $amount)`. You could also strip everything but numbers using `preg_replace()` but I don't have a clue what you're trying to do, so I don't know if you need that.

You didn't really give us any actual info or say what you're doing with the data, so we have no idea what you want the data to be.

Comment: I am trying to send this number, 4240, as 4240, with no comma. So why is it inserting the comma?

Comment: Just like I said that's how the API works. Stop asking why there's a comma now.